# Watson discovery app not working with JSON

Tags: json, dataset, ibm-watson, watson-discovery, data-collection

Hi I am trying to upload a json file as a data set in watson discovery console. Normally for PDFs and other accepted file formats, data enrichments (keywords, entity, taxonomy etc.) are AUTOMATICALLY created by the Discovery application. However if I upload the data set in JSON, it does not do the same.

Is there any particular JSON format that needs to be followed? And am I right that it automatically inserts the enrichments on it own?

Answer (score 1):

### What may be happening

I'm going to guess that you are using the `Default Configuration` provided by Watson Discovery. `Default Configuration` applies enrichments to a single field in the input data, the field named `text`. The converters for HTML, PDF and Microsoft Word will, by default, output the body of the document into the JSON field `text`. When you send JSON into Watson Discovery, no conversion is done—the field names pass straight through.

### What you can try

1. Adjust your input JSON to have a top level field named `text` which contains the text you want to be enriched.
2. Make and use a custom configuration which one or more entries under `enrichments` which have the value of `source_field` be the name of the field in your JSON that you want Watson Discovery to enrich.

Watson Discovery Tooling can be very helpful for experimenting with custom configurations.

### Example

To get concrete about this. Here is the `enrichments` portion of `Default Configuration`:

```js
"enrichments": [{
  "destination_field": "enriched_text",
  "source_field": "text",
  "enrichment": "alchemy_language",
  "options": {
    "extract": "keyword, entity, doc-sentiment, taxonomy, concept, relation",
    "sentiment": true,
    "quotations": true
  }
}]
```

If your JSON has English text in a field named `paragraphs` and you would like Watson Discovery to provide enrichments for that field, you could use this configuration:

```js
"enrichments": [{
  "destination_field": "enriched_paragraphs",
  "source_field": "paragraphs",
  "enrichment": "alchemy_language",
  "options": {
    "extract": "keyword, entity, doc-sentiment, taxonomy, concept, relation",
    "sentiment": true,
    "quotations": true
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload inside interface and with `cURL`.

See one example (cURL) - Create a collection:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "name": "test_collection",
  "description": "My test collection",
  "configuration_id": "{configuration_id}"
}' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections?version=2016-12-01"
```

You will set `"Content-Type: application/json"`. Insert your `username` and `password` with the `Service Credentials`. And set your enviromenment_id inside the URL.

Add some document:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -F file=@sample1.html "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/documents?version=2016-12-01"
```

Obs.: The document to ingest. The maximum supported file size is *50 megabytes*. Files larger than 50 megabytes are rejected. The API detects the *document type*, but you can specify it if incorrect. Acceptable MIME type values are `application/json`, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/pdf, text/html, and application/xhtml+xml. Specify content type in the multipart form as `type=`.

```
curl -X PUT -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_ID}/configurations/{Configuration_ID}?version=2016-12-01"
```

See the [official](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?curl#create-collection) API Reference documentation.